# C# ICMPv6 checksum calculation

Tags: c#, checksum

I need to compute ICMPv6 checksum. I have found correct manual in RFC 2460 and written code in c#, which is pasted below. In a code you can see that i add to checksum source IP, destination IP of packet, than ICMPv6 message length (which is 32 bytes for Neighbor Advertisement) and then i add next header ID which is 58 for ICMPv6. Then there is FOR cycle, which adds to checksum whole ICMPv6 message (which starts with message type i believe, e.g. 88 00 ... for Neighbor advertisement). Than i made calculations and complements checksum, but it's wrong. I am trying to compute this checksum for real sniffed Neighbor Advertisement, which is also below, but i can't get the same checksum. What could be wrong in my code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ICaptureDevice device = new OfflineCaptureDevice("icmp.pcap");
        device.Open();

        device.OnPacketArrival += new SharpPcap.PacketArrivalEventHandler(device_OnPacketArrival);
        device.Capture();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, SharpPcap.CaptureEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //packet conversions
            var packet = PacketDotNet.Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet);
            var ethernetPacket = ((PacketDotNet.EthernetPacket)packet);
            int dlzka_packetu = e.Packet.Data.Length;
            string eth = BitConverter.ToString(ethernetPacket.Bytes);

            //now its in string field format - one string item is one byte, e.g. FF
            string[] eth_final2 = eth.Split('-');
            foreach (string bytes in eth_final2) { Console.Write(bytes + " "); }
            Console.WriteLine();

            //taking out source IP
            IPAddress src_ip = IPAddress.Parse(eth_final2[22]+eth_final2[23]+":"+eth_final2[24]+eth_final2[25]+":"+eth_final2[26]+eth_final2[27]+":"+eth_final2[28]+eth_final2[29]+":"+eth_final2[30]+eth_final2[31]+":"+eth_final2[32]+eth_final2[33]+":"+eth_final2[34]+eth_final2[35]+":"+eth_final2[36]+eth_final2[37]);

            //destination IP
            IPAddress dst_ip = IPAddress.Parse(eth_final2[38] + eth_final2[39] + ":" + eth_final2[40] + eth_final2[41] + ":" + eth_final2[42] + eth_final2[43] + ":" + eth_final2[44] + eth_final2[45] + ":" + eth_final2[46] + eth_final2[47] + ":" + eth_final2[48] + eth_final2[49] + ":" + eth_final2[50] + eth_final2[51] + ":" + eth_final2[52] + eth_final2[53]);

            Console.WriteLine(src_ip);
            Console.WriteLine(dst_ip);
            int icmpv6_length = 32;
            int next_header = 58;
            Console.WriteLine();

            string icmp_payload = "";

            //taking out ICMPv6 message
            for (int i = 54; i < 54 + 32; i++)
            {
                if (i == 56 || i == 57) { icmp_payload += "00"; }
                else icmp_payload += eth_final2[i];
            }

            Console.WriteLine(icmp_payload);
            byte[] icmp_bytes = GetStringToBytes(icmp_payload);


            //CALLING THE FUNCTION ICMPchecksum
            ushort sum = ICMPchecksum(src_ip.GetAddressBytes(), dst_ip.GetAddressBytes(), BitConverter.GetBytes(icmpv6_length), BitConverter.GetBytes(next_header), icmp_bytes);

            Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString("X"));


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
        }


    }

    static byte[] GetStringToBytes(string value)
    {
        SoapHexBinary shb = SoapHexBinary.Parse(value);
        return shb.Value;
    }

    static ushort ICMPchecksum(byte[] src_ip, byte[] dst_ip, byte[] length, byte[] next, byte[] payload)
    {
        ushort checksum = 0;

        //length of byte fields
        Console.WriteLine("src_ip: "+src_ip.Length+" dst_ip: "+dst_ip.Length+" length: "+length.Length+" next_header: "+next.Length+" payload: "+payload.Length);

        //display all fields, which will be used for checksum calculation
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(src_ip));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(dst_ip));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(length));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(next));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(payload));


        //ADDS SOURCE IPv6 address
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 0);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 2);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 4);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 6);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 8);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 10);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 12);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(src_ip, 14);

        //ADDS DEST IPv6 address
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 0);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 2);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 4);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 6);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 8);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 10);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 12);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(dst_ip, 14);

        //ADDS LENGTH OF ICMPv6 packet
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(length, 0);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(length, 2);

        //ADDS NEXT HEADER ID = 58
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(next, 0);
        checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(next, 2);

        //ADDS WHOLE ICMPv6 message
        for (int i = 0; i < payload.Length; i = i + 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            checksum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(payload, i);
        }

        checksum += (ushort)(checksum >> 16);

        return (ushort)~checksum;
    }
```

And here is packet screen.

only link : http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/7237/icmpv6.png

plus the link, where you can download the file, i am using for testing:

http://www.2shared.com/file/wIETWTWB/icmp.html

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you add the function call (ie the exact values of the parameters in your example)?

Comment: "which starts with message type i believe" - You need to confirm if your believe is correct or not.

Comment: parameters for the function are:
src_ip = fe80::219:55ff:fe27:27d0
dst_ip = fe80::222:75ff:fed6:fe50
as a payload is used the ICMPv6 message, as it is signed in picture i have posted in my question. The length is length of ICMPv6 message which is 32, next header ID is 58. All is converted to byte[] and pushed to the function you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a payload is used the ICMPv6 message, as it is signed in picture i have posted in my question

At least that is wrong. when you calculate the checksum, you should replace the bytes representing the checksum itself with 0 first.

### Update

Based on your icmp.pcap I have created a standalone program to calculate the checksum. See below for the full source.

The most important error is:

```
    ushort checksum = 0;
```

Although the checksum is 16-bit, this algorithm requires at least 32-bits for temporary values:

```
    uint checksum = 0;
```

The checksum calculation requires [ones' complement arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) where the carry of an addition wraps around. To improve performance, all wrapping is done at the end;

```
checksum += (ushort)(checksum >> 16);
```

But that is only possible if checksum has more than 16 bits. Otherwise this line would be useless.

But there is something else to take in account. The BitConverter.ToUInt16 depends on the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your processor, which is probably Little Endian. That will make the result `A5AB`. Which is probably not as you expect, but if you switch bytes, you get the correct version. I inserted a function from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/15179/adapt-systembitconverter-to-handle-big-endian-network-byte-ordering-in-order-to-create-number-types-from-bytes-and-viceversa/) to fix that. That will make the result `ABA5`. On the other hand, if you don't set the checksum to 0 before the calculation, the ICMPchecksum will always [return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460075/33499) if the checksum is valid. Also note that your function cannot handle a odd length of the payload.

```
class Program {
    static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        byte[] src_ip = new byte[]
                            {
                                0xfe, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                                0x02, 0x19, 0x55, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x27, 0x27, 0xd0
                            };

        byte[] dst_ip = new byte[]
                            {
                                0xfe, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                                0x02, 0x22, 0x75, 0xff, 0xfe, 0xd6, 0xfe, 0x50
                            };
        byte[] length = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 32};
        byte [] next = new byte [] { 0, 0, 0, 58 };
        byte[] payload = new byte[]
                             {
                                 0x88, 0x00, 0xab, 0xa5, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                                 0xfe, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                                 0x02, 0x19, 0x55, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x27, 0x27, 0xd0,
                                 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x19, 0x55, 0x27, 0x27, 0xd0
                             };
#if true
        payload [2] = 0;
        payload [3] = 0;
#endif

        ushort checksum = ICMPchecksum(src_ip, dst_ip, length, next, payload);

        Console.WriteLine (checksum.ToString ("X"));
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }

    public static ushort BitConverterToUInt16 (byte [] value, int startIndex)
    {
#if false
            return System.BitConverter.ToUInt16 (value, startIndex);
#else
            return System.BitConverter.ToUInt16 (value.Reverse ().ToArray (), value.Length - sizeof (UInt16) - startIndex);
#endif
    }

    static ushort ICMPchecksum (byte [] src_ip, byte [] dst_ip, byte [] length, byte [] next, byte [] payload)
    {
        uint checksum = 0;

        //length of byte fields
        Console.WriteLine ("src_ip: " + src_ip.Length + " dst_ip: " + dst_ip.Length + " length: " + length.Length + " next_header: " + next.Length + " payload: " + payload.Length);

        //display all fields, which will be used for checksum calculation
        Console.WriteLine (BitConverter.ToString (src_ip));
        Console.WriteLine (BitConverter.ToString (dst_ip));
        Console.WriteLine (BitConverter.ToString (length));
        Console.WriteLine (BitConverter.ToString (next));
        Console.WriteLine (BitConverter.ToString (payload));


        //ADDS SOURCE IPv6 address
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 0);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 2);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 4);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 6);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 8);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 10);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 12);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (src_ip, 14);

        //ADDS DEST IPv6 address
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 0);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 2);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 4);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 6);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 8);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 10);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 12);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (dst_ip, 14);

        //ADDS LENGTH OF ICMPv6 packet
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (length, 0);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (length, 2);

        //ADDS NEXT HEADER ID = 58
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (next, 0);
        checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (next, 2);

        //ADDS WHOLE ICMPv6 message
        for (int i = 0; i < payload.Length; i = i + 2) {
            Console.WriteLine (i);
            checksum += BitConverterToUInt16 (payload, i);
        }

        checksum += (ushort)(checksum >> 16);

        return (ushort)~checksum;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is right, but i have done that in my code, before the function call. I apologize i forgot to write about that. ICMPv6 message is taken as marked on picture, but checksum field is set to 0000 instead of aba5. May there be a problem with order of adding of parameters to the checksum? i am adding source ip, dest ip, icmpv6 message length, next header id and then icmpv6 message...maybe that is the problem (or it is not)

Comment: @user1317200 That's why I asked for the (complete) function call. Also I have doubts about the algorithm you use. But I can't tell from just reading the code. But I still think it is more likely there is something else wrong with the function call, for example in the way you create the arrays. Because my answer was not fully correct, you probably should not have selected it as answer. So I think you should either unmark it, and edit the question or ask a new question. And please add the call you use, so people can copy/paste to try the code. For example post it like a unit test.

Comment: Ok, i have done it as you have requested, pasted whole code to question, and pasted link for download the pcap file with used packet. Thank you very much for your interest i hope we will correct my code. And i apologize for weird code, i am not very good programmer.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the code included returns the correct checksum.

Comment: You have no idea, how much i am thankful to you. Code is certainly perfect i am going to remake it for caught packets. Thanks again, i think this will help more people looking for the answer. 
Have a nice day.